# sed to grep lines after specific line for further processing

Tags: shell, sed, tcl

I am working with a script which looks for file lines  after a  specific line and process them to get data from it.

Let me illustrate with an example,
 if file "sample.log" has lines like

```
qwerty asdf foo bar
foo 
time: 1:00 PM
foo1 bar1
foo foo fooo copying file abc/def/ghi/foo.txt
bar bar1 bar2 copying file efg/qwe/bar.txt
foo
```

My script should search for contents after time: 1:00 PM. After finding those lines, it must look for lines matching the pattern "copying" and get the  path specified in the line.

In this case, output written to another file should be

```
abc/def/ghi/foo.txt
efg/qwe/bar.txt
```

I tried this using following command but getting empty string as output. Please guide me with this

```
    sed -n '/^time: 1:00 PM/{/^(.*)copying file/s/^(.*)copying file //p}' ../../sample.log
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're already in Tcl, you could code it in Tcl:

```
set fid [open "FILE" r]
set have_time false
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    if {$have_time && [regexp {copying file (.*)} $line -> filename]} {
        puts $filename
    } elseif {[string first "time:" $line] > -1} {
        set have_time true
    }
}
close $fid
```

If your file is quite huge, `exec sed` may be faster, but you'll have to see for yourself.

Note, if you're going to `exec sed`, keep in mind that inside Tcl, single quotes have no special meaning: use braces to quote the sed program.

```
exec sed -e {do stuff here} FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/1:00 PM/,$ {/copying/s:.*file \(.*\):\1:p};d' FILE
```

Comment: thanks! but i find it not working when i execute the same from a tcl file using command

exec /bin/sh -c "sed '/1:00 PM/,$ {/copying/s:.*file \(.*\):\1:p};d' FILE"

why is that?

Comment: You need the backslashes around the parentheses, @NathanPk; those are part of the sed syntax, not just shell escapage.  Otherwise it looks for literal parentheses in the file instead of capturing part of the line.

Comment: @Mark Reed : Even in that case I am getting an empty string as output. It works fine in command prompt. Any other modification to be done?

Comment: If you call the command from some programminng language, you need to take into account that the string that represent the command will be evaluated before to call it, so a string "\a" will become "a". Dedending on your language, you need to write the string such that after evaluation, it be `\a`, not `a`.

Comment: The `\1` inside a Tcl double-quoted string turns into a character code 1.  Double all the backslashes: `"sed '/1:00 PM/,$ {/copying/s:.*file \\(.*\\):\\1:p};d' FILE"`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/1:00 PM/,$!b' -e 's/.*copying.* //w copy' file
```